# Spring get managed beans during a method invocation

Tags: java, spring, instantiation

i'm new to spring, and i have a question that i couldn't find an answer for it - 
during a method execution, i need to create new instances of a managed bean (scope == prototype) in a pre-defined quantity:

```
@Component
class SomeClass
{
     @Resource
     private ConnectionFactory conFactory;

     private Set <Client> clients;

     @Value ("${clientsNum}")
     private int clientsNum; 

     public void init ()
     {
         Client client = null;    //an interface, that the managed bean implements.

         for (int i = 0; i < clientsNum; i++)
         {
               client = ... //how to get a new client instance? 
               clients.add (client);
               client.doSomething ();
         }
     }

     public void shutdown ()
     {
         for (Client client : clients)
               client.shutdown ();

         conFactory.shutdown ();
     }
 }
```

how do i do that?

i know i can use the init-method \ @PostConstruct annotation (and the matching destroy method), but i don't know how to get the instances according to the required amount.

i searched for the issue in the past few days, and read about service locator, lookup method and factory bean. they all use CGLIB (which i prefer NOT to use) or spring's ApplicationContext (which creates a dependency in spring's implementation), and above all - they don't handle the creation of beans during a method invocation (or at least - i didn't understand how to use them during the invocation).

please assist.

thanks.

**EDIT:**

eventually i realized that i have to use either CGLIB or Spring's application context, and i chose to use the [service locator](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/ServiceLocatorFactoryBean.html) option.

Comment: What is the Problem you want to solve? - I think the reason why you do not find a reasonable answer is, that you want to solve a problem in a not spring way. - Therefore I ask for the problem.

Comment: i don't know how to get a new instance of the managed bean, without using injection, but during a method invocation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid you have to use CGLIB or `ApplicationContext` since you wanted a *managed bean*.

## Lookup method injection

Add a [lookup method](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.1.0.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-lookup-method-injection) to your `SomeClass`:

```
@Lookup
private Client createClient() {
  return null; // Never mind, this method will be overridden
}
```

Then in `init()`, you can just call it:

```
client = createClient();
```

Note that [@Lookup](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.1.0.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Lookup.html) annotation was introduced in Spring 4.1.0. You need XML config if you're using older versions.

## Using ApplicationContext

Declare an auto wired property:

```
@Autowired
private ApplicationContext applicationContext;
```

And in `init()`:

```
client = applicationContext.getBean(Client.class);
```

Comment: thanks. i realized that i have to use CGLIB or Spring's application context.
eventually, i decided to use service locator.

Answer (score 0):

I guess some type of factory would be a better choice for you, you may define a factory method which takes clientsNum as parameter and returns a set to you. This way you can hide all the details from your service class.
If you still want to do this using dependency injection you can try method injection. Have a look at following code to get an idea.

```
@Component
class SomeClass
{
 @Resource
 private ConnectionFactory conFactory;
 protected abstract Client createClient();

 private Set <Client> clients;

 @Value ("${clientsNum}")
 private int clientsNum; 

 public void init ()
 {
     Client client = null;    //an interface, that the managed bean implements.

     for (int i = 0; i < clientsNum; i++)
     {
           client = createClient();
           clients.add (client);
           client.doSomething ();
     }
 }

 public void shutdown ()
 {
     for (Client client : clients)
           client.shutdown ();

     conFactory.shutdown ();
 }
}
```

You can find a complete example for method injection with simple google search. But i recommend going with the first solution, its more clean.

Answer (score 0):

> i don't know how to get a new instance of the managed bean, without using injection, but during a method invocation.

Inject the Spring ApplicationContextand then use `ApplicationContext.getBean(...)`

```
 @Autowired
 private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

 public void init ()
 {
     Client client = null;    //an interface, that the managed bean implements.
     for (int i = 0; i < clientsNum; i++)
     {
/*>>>>*/   client = applicationContext.getBean(Client.class); 
           clients.add (client);
           client.doSomething ();
     }
 }
```